# Why do some questions appear with a red background?

Tags: discussion, support

As I was looking through some of the unanswered questions I noticed that some were appearing with a red background like the one in the photo below. Does anyone know what it means?
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It means the question contains tags that you have in your list of "Favorite Tags", which you can see in the right column on the main site.

[image]

Comment: Somewhat confusingly, that looks almost exactly like the red background that most SE sites use for deleted questions and answers.